# TypeORM "OR" operator

Tags: sql, typescript, operators, typeorm

I could not find any notion of OR operator neither in TypeORM docs nor in the source code. does it support it at all?

I'm trying to do perform a basic search with a repository.

```js
db.getRepository(MyModel).find({
  name : "john",
  lastName: "doe"
})
```

I know this generates an AND operation but
I need an OR operation so SQL would look like:

```
name='john' OR lastName='doe'
```

Am I forced to use the query builder for something basic like this?

Answer (score 134):

```
db.getRepository(MyModel).find({
  where: [
      { name: "john" },
      { lastName: "doe" }
  ]
})
```

Pass an array to `where`

Comment: sorry this dosnt work. you get this error:
'filter' field must be of BSON type object

Comment: Ok i figured it out. this will only work with SQL databases and not Mongo.

Comment: Works for Postgres. The question is, now, how to combine this "OR" sub-clause with additional "AND" sub-clauses. Any ideas?

Comment: Add more properties to the object

Comment: Hm, how would one express parentheses?

Comment: This executes AND not OR

Comment: @AlexFortuna That's what I'm wondering as well, or alternatively wanting the top level clause to be an AND clause with an OR sub-clause. `WHERE (column_a = "foobar" AND (column_b = "foo" OR column_c = "bar"))`

Answer (score 18):

You can combine "OR" sub-clause with additional "AND" by doing the following.

```
db.getRepository(MyModel).find({
  where: [
      { name: "john", lastName: "doe" },
      { age: 20 }
  ]
})
```

This would result to

```
select * from model where (name = "john" and lastname = "doe") OR age = 20
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 14):

I had the same issue, but I worked around it with the [QueryBuilder](http://typeorm.io/#/select-query-builder).

This would be an example.

```
return await getRepository(MyModel)
  .createQueryBuilder()
  .where("name = :name OR lastName = :lastName", {
    name: "john",
    lastName: "doe"
  })
  .getMany();
```

Comment: Well, the other answer without QueryBuilder works well, but in case you'd like to use QueryBuilder anyway then you can also use [orWhere](https://typeorm.io/#/select-query-builder/adding-where-expression) to create your `OR` expression.

Answer (score 10):

To use `OR` in `sub-clause`, I have to repeat the `main-clause`

```
userRepository.find({
  where: [
    {
      firstName: 'Timber',
      lastName: 'Saw',
      project: {
        name: 'TypeORM',
      },
    },
    {
      firstName: 'Timber',
      lastName: 'Saw',
      project: {
        initials: 'TORM',
      },
    },
  ],
});
```

Find all `Timber Saw` have projects with `name = "TypeORM"`  or `initials = "TORM"`

Answer (score 3):

Since version [0.3.18](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#0318-2024-01-03) (released 2024-01-03), TypeORM now supports an `Or` operator in the basic .find* methods:

```
const users = await db.getRepository(User).findBy({
    name: Or(Equal("John"), ILike("Jane%")),
})
```

```sql
-- Will generate the following query:
SELECT * FROM "user" WHERE "name" = 'John' OR "name" ILIKE 'Jane%'
```

Unfortunately this does not solve the scenario you presented, but just cases where only one field is involved. It might still be useful to other users though.